# What was the modification by the Community♦ here?

Tags: support, community-user

I was browsing some unanswered questions and found a question asked by [Yogi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/489/yogi). [The question is in Page 58](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=58&tab=noanswers&pagesize=30) if there are 30 questions in each page (as of today).

[Why ashvalayana ghriya sutra dictates that bones of cremated person should be buried](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10466/5212)

When it is seen from questions page, it shows

[image: image of question modified by community]

> modified Apr 7 '16 at 15:15 by Community

We can see that it shows it is modified by question but when we look at the question, there is no modification from Community user.

I thought it was a bump to answer but there's no mention of that in the question's [timeline](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/10466/timeline).

Some questions were edited by Community♦ to replace http with https due to network wide https. But there was no question or answer linked in the question.

I was wondering what caused to show that it is modified by community. What was the modification?

Comment: Are there no deleted answers in the question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is one deleted answer but the user was not a deleted user. The deleted answer was converted to comment.

Comment: Think this explains it then: since the conversion was probably automatic, it's contributed to the Community account, which deleted the answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, moderator converted to comment at the time. Can you elaborate and add as an answer?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma There is 20 minutes difference between those times.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That makes more confusing. There are time differences between community bumping, Keshav converting to comment, User comment appearing in the comment section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Before May 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279201/260388), timeline used **not** to record the bumping action by community user.

And as pointed out in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43015/260388) (2010) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177726/260388) (2013) posts, "bumped to homepage by community user" had not recorded in the timeline.

I think this would be happened in this case, edit shows the time-step older than May 2016.